# PendingIntent sends void to activity

Tags: null, android-pendingintent

I am trying to send data from the notication to my newsdetails class.
but it always retuns null. I tried checking if I actually have data in my variables before sending and it seems I do, So I am trying to figure out why

so this is my MyFirebaseMessageService.class

```java
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewsDetails.class);
            //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

             String Link = data.get("picture_url");
             String Date = data.get("date");
             String Title = data.get("title");
             String Description = data.get("description");
             Log.d("Dateter", Date);
             if (Link != null ) {

                 intent.putExtra("Link",Link);
                 intent.putExtra("ThumbNail",Link);
             }
             if (Date != null ) {
                 intent.putExtra("Date",Date);
             }
            if (Title != null  ) {

                intent.putExtra("Title",Title);
            }
            if (Description !=null ) {
                intent.putExtra("Description",Description);
            }


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                    .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentInfo(notification.getTitle())
                    .setLargeIcon(icon)
                    .setColor(Color.BLUE)
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 300)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo24x24)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.logo24x24,"Open",pendingIntent);
```

and this is part of my Newsdetails.class *(Note that when I use it normally to open an article from my app it will open normally. it only gets Null from the notification. but the data is in MyFirebaseMessageService.class before lunching the intent. is there a different way to get data from pendingitentents? I am using same class for 2 reasons but same variables.

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.d("Title2",bundle.getString("Title"));
        date.setText(bundle.getString("Date"));
        titletext.setText(bundle.getString("Title"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the "extras" to the `Intent` **before** calling `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.

As you can see, you add the "extras" to the `Intent`, but **after** you've gotten a `PendingIntent` that wraps the `Intent`. The `PendingIntent` that you pass to the `Notification` does not have the "extras" in it.

Comment: Yes that actually makes sense. another newbie mistake, thanks a lot David !